# undefined variables after sharing with view composer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I want to share four variables to the views. I've following code:

**BannerServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BannerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(
            'frontend.*', 'App\ViewComposers\BannerComposer'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**BannerComposer.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Paragliding\Services\Frontend\BannerService;

class BannerComposer
{
    protected $banner;

    /**
     * Create a new banner composer.
     *
     * @param  BannerService $banner
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(BannerService $banner)
    {
        $this->banner = $banner;
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('belowFeaturedCompaniesLeft', $this->banner->getBelowFeaturedCompanyLeftBanner())
             ->with('belowFeaturedCompaniesRight', $this->banner->getBelowFeaturedCompanyRightBanner())
             ->with('rightFeaturedPackagesFirst', $this->banner->getFeaturedPackageRightFirstBanner())
             ->with('rightFeaturedPackagesSecond', $this->banner->getFeaturedPackageRightSecondBanner());
    }
}
```

**BannerService.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Paragliding\Services\Frontend;

use App\Http\Requests\BannerRequest;
use App\Paragliding\Models\Banner\Banner;
use App\Paragliding\Repositories\Banner\BannerRepository;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * Class BannerService
 * @package App\MNepal\Services\Admin
 */
class BannerService
{
    /**
     * @var BannerRepository
     */
    private $banner;
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $log;

    /**
     * BannerService constructor.
     * @param BannerRepository $banner
     * @param LoggerInterface $log
     */
    public function __construct(BannerRepository $banner,LoggerInterface $log)
    {
        $this->banner = $banner;
        $this->log = $log;
    }

    /**
     * Get Below Featured Company Left Banner
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getBelowFeaturedCompanyLeftBanner()
    {
        return $this->banner->getBelowFeaturedCompanyLeftBanner();
    }

    /**
     * Get Below Featured Company Right Banner
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getBelowFeaturedCompanyRightBanner()
    {
        return $this->banner->getBelowFeaturedCompanyRightBanner();
    }

    /**
     * Get First Banner on Right of Featured Packages
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getFeaturedPackageRightFirstBanner()
    {
        return $this->banner->getFeaturedPackageRightFirstBanner();
    }

     /**
     * Get Second Banner on Right of Featured Packages
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getFeaturedPackageRightSecondBanner()
    {
        return $this->banner->getFeaturedPackageRightSecondBanner();
    }
}
```

**BannerRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Paragliding\Repositories\Banner;

use App\Paragliding\Repositories\Repository;
use App\Paragliding\Models\Banner\BannerPosition;

class BannerRepository extends Repository
{

    /**
     * Get model name with namespace
     *
     * @return String
     */
    function getModel()
    {
        return 'App\Paragliding\Models\Banner\Banner';
    }

    /**
     * Get all the banner positions
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */
    public function getAllPositions()
    {
        return BannerPosition::all();
    }

    /**
     * Get left banner just below the featured companies section
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */

    public function getBelowFeaturedCompanyLeftBanner()
    {
        $this->model->whereIn('banner_position_id',BannerPosition::where('title','HOME_PAGE_BELOW_FEATURED_COMPANY_LEFT')->pluck('id'))->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get right banner just below the featured companies section
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */

    public function getBelowFeaturedCompanyRightBanner()
    {
        $this->model->whereIn('banner_position_id',BannerPosition::where('title','HOME_PAGE_BELOW_FEATURED_COMPANY_RIGHT')->pluck('id'))->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get first banner right to the featured packages section
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */

    public function getFeaturedPackageRightFirstBanner()
    {
        $this->model->whereIn('banner_position_id',BannerPosition::where('title','HOME_PAGE_RIGHT_OF_FEATURED_PACKAGES_FIRST')->pluck('id'))->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get first banner right to the featured packages section
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]
     */

    public function getFeaturedPackageRightSecondBanner()
    {
        $this->model->whereIn('banner_position_id',BannerPosition::where('title','HOME_PAGE_RIGHT_OF_FEATURED_PACKAGES_SECOND')->pluck('id'))->first();
    }

}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6 text-center">
  @if(isset($rightFeaturedPackagesFirst))
    <img src="{{asset('uploads/banners/'.$rightFeaturedPackagesFirst->image)}}" class="google-ad img-fluid text-center">
  @else
    <img src="{{asset('frontend/images/350x499.jpg')}}" class="google-ad img-fluid text-center">
  @endif

  @if(isset($rightFeaturedPackagesSecond))
    <img src="{{asset('uploads/banners/'.$rightFeaturedPackagesSecond->image)}}" class="google-ad img-fluid">
  @else
    <img src="{{asset('frontend/images/350x499.jpg')}}" class="google-ad img-fluid">
  @endif
</div>
```

**config/app.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
    | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
    | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
    |
    */

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Environment
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This value determines the "environment" your application is currently
    | running in. This may determine how you prefer to configure various
    | services your application utilizes. Set this in your ".env" file.
    |
    */

    'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'production'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Debug Mode
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When your application is in debug mode, detailed error messages with
    | stack traces will be shown on every error that occurs within your
    | application. If disabled, a simple generic error page is shown.
    |
    */

    'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application URL
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
    | the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
    | your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
    |
    */

    'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Timezone
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default timezone for your application, which
    | will be used by the PHP date and date-time functions. We have gone
    | ahead and set this to a sensible default for you out of the box.
    |
    */

    'timezone' => 'UTC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Locale Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
    | by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
    | to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
    |
    */

    'locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Encryption Key
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This key is used by the Illuminate encrypter service and should be set
    | to a random, 32 character string, otherwise these encrypted strings
    | will not be safe. Please do this before deploying an application!
    |
    */

    'key' => env('APP_KEY'),

    'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Logging Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the log settings for your application. Out of
    | the box, Laravel uses the Monolog PHP logging library. This gives
    | you a variety of powerful log handlers / formatters to utilize.
    |
    | Available Settings: "single", "daily", "syslog", "errorlog"
    |
    */

    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'single'),

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Autoloaded Service Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The service providers listed here will be automatically loaded on the
    | request to your application. Feel free to add your own services to
    | this array to grant expanded functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...
         */

        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\SettingServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BannerServiceProvider::class,

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [

        'App' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::class,
        'Artisan' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::class,
        'Auth' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::class,
        'Blade' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::class,
        'Broadcast' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::class,
        'Bus' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus::class,
        'Cache' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::class,
        'Config' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::class,
        'Cookie' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie::class,
        'Crypt' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt::class,
        'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
        'Eloquent' => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::class,
        'Event' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event::class,
        'File' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::class,
        'Gate' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class,
        'Hash' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash::class,
        'Lang' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang::class,
        'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
        'Mail' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::class,
        'Notification' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification::class,
        'Password' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::class,
        'Queue' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue::class,
        'Redirect' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::class,
        'Redis' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis::class,
        'Request' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::class,
        'Response' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::class,
        'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,
        'Schema' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::class,
        'Session' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::class,
        'Storage' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::class,
        'URL' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::class,
        'Validator' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::class,
        'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,

    ],

];
```

I've watching above code from hours and then searched a lot of questions still don't know what's wrong with the above code.

Here is the error screenshot.

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Can you also provide your `config/app.php`?

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I'll add have a look

Comment: Where is your 'index.blade.php' located?